# Storing Days in mysql Database

Tags: mysql

I would like to know the most efficient way of storing days of the week in a mysql database. I have a list of events that occur every week and want to return them in a list format as a schedule on the matching day.

I'm not sure which is the best way to go about this as it's not a specific date just rather a day?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your particular scenario I would go with [ENUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html) type, it is both readable and efficient.

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE
(
 -- other fields
  EVENT_DAY ENUM('SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY')
);
```

The nice thing about ENUMs is that you can write queries that are easy to read (e.g., `WHERE EVENT_DAY = 'FRIDAY'`) without giving up on performance, since internally MySQL stores data efficiently using a numeric representation.

---

Just to play the Devil's Advocate, Chris Komlenic wrote a very interesting [post](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/) recommending Reference Tables instead of enums. Anyway, I think that your problem fits his article "Criteria for when it might be okay to use enum". And a reference table to model days of the week sounds a little bit overkill (I would go with `TINYINT` as a second option).

Comment: This doesn't work if an event occurs more than a day in a week like every Wednesday and Friday.

Comment: Foreveer,  the OP did not need it. Anyway, there is also a [`SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html) type.

Comment: As I recall, `ENUM` is actually stored as a lookup table in MySQL. If true, then there is no reason to create your own lookup table in this simple case.

Comment: Hi @ButtleButkus, that was the intention of the example. `MY_TABLE` is a regular business table (e.g., `EVENT` table). Of course that if the enum values are needed in several tables there is nothing wrong about having a dedicated table for it (I would even reconsider the ENUM altogether)

Comment: I was agreeing with you! It's too bad MySQL doesn't have user-defined data types or else this solution would be even more useful. You could define the `DAYS` data type as this ENUM and then use it everywhere, and MySQL would handle the reference table for all in the background.

Answer (score 3):

You can store the weekdays and their standard ODBC index numbers in a table. (Use the INNODB engine throughout.)

```
create table weekdays (
  weekday_num integer primary key,
  day_of_week char(3) not null,
  unique (day_of_week)
);

-- Values correspond to return values from the dayofweek() function.
insert into weekdays values (1, 'Sun');
insert into weekdays values (2, 'Mon');
insert into weekdays values (3, 'Tue');
insert into weekdays values (4, 'Wed');
insert into weekdays values (5, 'Thu');
insert into weekdays values (6, 'Fri');
insert into weekdays values (7, 'Sat');
```

If application programs need to present these days and their indexes in a list, they can just query the database for the right values. (Or generate code by querying the database during `make <your_program_name>`.)

Then create a table of recurring events.

```
create table recurring_events (
  event_name varchar(20) primary key,
  day_of_week char(3) not null,
  foreign key (day_of_week) references weekdays (day_of_week)
);

insert into recurring_events values
('Trash pickup', 'Mon'),
('Bookmobile', 'Mon'),
('Grocery store', 'Wed'),
('Tutoring', 'Fri');
```

Using a join means the dbms should be able to avoid evaluating dayofweek() for every row in your table.

```
select e.*
from recurring_events e
inner join weekdays w on e.day_of_week = w.day_of_week
and dayofweek(current_date) = w.weekday_num;
```

Comment: This has the advantage of being able to sort results based on the day of week in order, although dealing with locales that start the week on a different day (e.g. Monday) becomes a little more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Another option can be to use the `ENUM` field to store days of week in either integer or string form. Depends on your particular implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Store it as a normal datetime, and use the function [`DAYOFWEEK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) to determine which day of the week it is.

For example, let's say you want to run a query that will return all rows that are supposed to occur on Monday:

```
SELECT event
FROM scheduled_events
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(event_datetime) = 2;
```

Comment: This doesn't work in this case, because the events occur every week (not on a specific date). You could always put in a dummy datetime where the DAYOFWEEK came out to the number you wanted, but then you might as well just store that integer and have an enumerated list to compare against.

Comment: @Aaron OP stated: "I have a list of events that occur every week..." What about this does not meet that criteria?

Comment: I understood that to mean that he has a list of events, and each of those events is on a day of the week (e.g. a class schedule that repeats weekly). You wouldn't put in a new entry for each instance of the event every week; you'd create one entry for the event for every week. In that case there is no specific datetime that the event occurs on - it occurs every Monday, for example, not a specific Monday.